# Circular seating arrangment stat question

Tags: statistics

If 15 people, including Alice and Bob, are randomly seated around a circular table, what is the probability that Alice and Bob are NOT next to each other?

I think that the answer is $$\left(n-1\right)!-\frac{2}{\left(n-1\right)}$$
because that is number of ways to sit around the table minus the number of ways alice is next to bob. Is this correct?

Comment: If you mean $n = 15$, then that number is approximately $87178291199.9$. Does that sound like a probability?

Comment: per @lulu comment, good idea to start with small $n$ and work upward to general case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alice has to be seated somewhere.  After Alice is seated, there are 14 remaining seats where Bob could sit.  12 of those remaining seats are not next to Alice.

Therefore, the probability that Bob and Alice are not next to each other is $\frac {12} {14} = \frac 6 7$